# ERROR in netcdf Installation

Tags: software-installation, make

```
user@user-HP-PC:~/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1$ make check
Making check in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/include'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/include'
Making check in libdispatch
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/libdispatch'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/libdispatch'
Making check in libsrc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/libsrc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/libsrc'
Making check in liblib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/liblib'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/liblib'
Making check in ncgen3
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
make  check-TESTS
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
PASS: run_tests.sh
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for netCDF 4.3.3.1
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen3'
Making check in ncgen
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
make  check-TESTS
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
PASS: run_tests.sh
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for netCDF 4.3.3.1
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncgen'
Making check in ncdump
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make  check-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
Making check in cdl
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/cdl'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/cdl'
Making check in expected
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/expected'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/expected'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make  rewrite-scalar ctest ctest64 ncdump tst_utf8 bom 
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[4]: `rewrite-scalar' is up to date.
make[4]: `ctest' is up to date.
make[4]: `ctest64' is up to date.
make[4]: `ncdump' is up to date.
make[4]: `tst_utf8' is up to date.
make[4]: `bom' is up to date.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make  check-TESTS
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
PASS: run_tests.sh
PASS: tst_64bit.sh
PASS: ctest
PASS: ctest64
PASS: tst_output.sh
PASS: tst_lengths.sh
PASS: tst_calendars.sh
PASS: tst_utf8
PASS: run_utf8_tests.sh
PASS: tst_nccopy3.sh
PASS: tst_charfill.sh
PASS: tst_iter.sh
PASS: tst_formatx3.sh
PASS: tst_bom.sh
FAIL: tst_ncgen4_classic.sh
make[6]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make  all-recursive
make[7]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
Making all in cdl
make[8]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/cdl'
make[8]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/cdl'
Making all in expected
make[8]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/expected'
make[8]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump/expected'
make[8]: Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[8]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for netCDF 4.3.3.1
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 15
# PASS:  14
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See ncdump/test-suite.log
Please report to support-netcdf@unidata.ucar.edu
============================================================================
make[5]: *** [test-suite.log] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make[1]: *** [check] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Downloads/netcdf-4.3.3.1/ncdump'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: if I use "make check" am getting above error, but not for "sudo make check".  How to confirm  whether it is installed properly or not...???

Answer (score 0):

The command `make check` or the command `sudo make check` installs nothing. Therefore, it is **exceptionally** fine to use `sudo`. This has no effect on the installed program.

Install with

```
sudo make install
```

Or create and install a DEB package with `checkinstall`

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```